# Flink error - org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4

Tags: maven, hadoop, apache-flink

I am trying to run a flink job using a file from HDFS. I have created a dataset as following -

```
DataSource<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>> visits = env.readHadoopFile(new TextInputFormat(), LongWritable.class,Text.class, Config.pathToVisits());
```

I am using flink's latest version - 0.9.0-milestone-1-hadoop1
(I have also tried with 0.9.0-milestone-1)

whereas my Hadoop version is 2.6.0

But, I get the following exception when I try to execute the job. I have searched for similar problem, and it is related to version incompatibility between client and hdfs.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Can you please let me know what changes should I make in my pom, so that it points to correct Hadoop/HDFS version? or changes elsewhere?
Or I need to downgrade the hadoop installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the Hadoop-2 build of Flink? Have a look at the [downloads page](http://flink.apache.org/downloads.html#preview-release). There is a build called `flink-0.9.0-milestone-1-bin-hadoop2.tgz` that should work with Hadoop 2.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, it worked after adding hadoop2 main dist-jar to the project. Is there any alternate way where I can refer to this (Hadoop 2) build version from pom? (Do we have hadoop2 build in maven repository for 0.9?) I tried 0.9.0-milestone-1-hadoop1 and 0.9.0-milestone-1 but in vain.

Comment: What kind of setup do you have (local, cluster, YARN) and how do you submit your Flink program?

Comment: It is mostly local, and for some experiments I am using a cluster. I am running flink programs directly from the IDE.